# laravel websockets cannot be served

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, websocket

I am trying to use websockets following the documentation of https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/ after typing "php artisan websockets:serve" i get this following error

Whoops\Exception\ErrorException  : Class BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\Statistics\DnsResolver may not inherit from final class (React\Dns\Resolver\Resolver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you encounter is caused by a backwards incompatible change in the `React\Dns` package causing the `BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets` package to fail. Others have reported this issue [on github](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets/issues/216) as well. The solution for this would be to downgrade the `React\Dns` package, until `BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets` fixes this issue themselves. Downgrading can be done like so:

```
composer require react/dns:^0.4.19
```

After you've done so try running `php artisan websockets:serve` again to see if the issue is resolved.